# force to bring excel window to the front?

Tags: c#, excel

i have a small application developed in `C# .NET` that manipulate excel sheets, I don't know why some users keep telling me that when they open the excel file the window doesn't appear on front/top although I set the visible to true and the window state on maximized.

This is the function that reads the *excel* file:

```
public static void OpenExcel(string fileName, bool visibility, FunctionToExecute fn = null)
{
    string addInPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Microsoft\\AddIns\\mDF_XLcalendar.xla");

    deleg = fn;
    app = new Excel.Application();

    app.Workbooks.Open(addInPath);
    app.Workbooks.Open(fileName);

    app.ScreenUpdating = true;
    app.DisplayAlerts = true;
    app.Visible = visibility;
    app.UserControl = true;
    app.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized;

    EventDel_BeforeBookClose = new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler(application_WorkbookBeforeClose);
    EventSave_BeforeBookClose = new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeSaveEventHandler(Open_ExcelApp_WorkbookBeforeSave);

    app.WorkbookBeforeClose += EventDel_BeforeBookClose;
    app.WorkbookBeforeSave += EventSave_BeforeBookClose;     
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Would it be because you are setting the `WindowState` after you actually open the workbook?

Comment: If your .Net code still have some code left to execute after your Excel app opens then it would set focus back to your program. And if your program had GUI then it would be on top of Excel. So one thing you can try is to move the line openning Excel to the end of ur your code

Comment: i tried this but it didn't work, and the thing is that i can't reproduce the problem on my machine because it works well on mine...

Comment: I have an Excel application open, and 2 excel workbooks open and minimized,
When i try to activate the workbook i want (by workbookname) and then app.activewindow.activate, it doesn't always bring the workbook i want to active state, kindly help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try to activate the excel window by

```
app.ActiveWindow.Activate();
```

If this doesn't work you might find other solutions (involving Native WinAPI calls) at [this thread at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3aad837c-e039-4a17-8907-9153d3b7b923/how-to-bring-an-excel-app-to-the-front-make-it-active-application-)

Answer (score 11):

some magic, that work for me:

```
app.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMinimized; // -4140
app.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMaximized; // -4137
```

Comment: This answer has the benefit that it works even if the application has not yet opened a Workbook.

Answer (score 7):

I found this to work.  [How to bring an Excel app to the front](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3aad837c-e039-4a17-8907-9153d3b7b923/how-to-bring-an-excel-app-to-the-front-make-it-active-application-)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);   

public static void BringExcelWindowToFront(Application xlApp)
{

   string caption = xlApp.Caption;
   IntPtr handler = FindWindow(null, caption);
   SetForegroundWindow(handler);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes if there is more than one file open at same time in Excel, `ActiveWindow.Activate()` will not work.

A successful trick is to do minimize then maximize commands.

Answer (score 2):

A little late I know, but why the need to use FindWindow, the Windows handle is accessible via the Application :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

public static void BringExcelWindowToFront(Application xlApp)
{
   SetForegroundWindow((IntPtr)xlApp.Hwnd);  // Note Hwnd is declared as int
}
```

There will be no problems if more than one window has the same caption.

Answer (score 0):

To activate a specific workbook:

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

  public static void BringExcelWindowToFront(Excel._Workbook xlBook)
  {
     var windows = xlBook.Windows;
     foreach (Excel.Window window in windows)
     {
        IntPtr handler = (IntPtr)window.Hwnd;

        SetForegroundWindow(handler);
        return;
     }
  }
```