# How do you bring an Office 365 Excel Workbook to the front?

Tags: .net, excel

Suppose you have a bunch of Excel Workbooks open, but you want to bring one to the front to get the user interacting with that book.  How do you do this?

I am currently using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version 15.0.0.0.

I tried without success:

```
Excel.Workbook output = app.Workbooks[path];
(Excel._Workbook)output).Activate();
```

Also

```
  foreach (Excel.Windows w in ((Excel._Workbook)output).Windows)
    w.*something*
```

The question, [force to bring excel window to the front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118881/force-to-bring-excel-window-to-the-front) does not apply because 365 has abandoned MDI for having separate windows for each workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a combination of the answers from the referenced page:

1. Use Windows to find the Excel app window (one of them) and bring it forward.
2. Use Excel to activate the workbook you need.

```
BringExcelWindowToFront(app);
((Excel._Workbook)output).Activate();
```

Here's the support code to do the first part:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

public static void BringExcelWindowToFront(Excel.Application xlApp)
{

  string caption = xlApp.Caption;
  IntPtr handler = FindWindow(null, caption);
  SetForegroundWindow(handler);
}
```